# hibernate tools & hibernate template in DAO

Tags: spring, hibernate, dao, hibernate-tools

I used Hibernate tools Eclipse plugin to generate the DAO implementation but it uses a "javax.persistence.EntityManager". I want to generate a DAO impl based on my mapped entity(using JPA annotations) that use a Hibernate Template provided by Spring Framework. How can I do this?

Comment: i found online "Skyway builder". Is a useful tool?

Comment: HibernateTemplate is almost deprecated (the documentation advises not to use it anymore). How about generating the DAOs by yourself? You would learn more than having magic tools generate them for you.

Comment: thanks for the advice. So I can use default EntityManager?

Comment: You have to decide if you want to use Hibernate using the JPA API (EntityManager, standard) or the native API (Session, proprietary).

Answer (score 0):

This is how we used to generated DAO objects based with generic implementation of DAO Impl by using Hibernate Template provided by Spring Framework.

Generating DAO java class with ftl,And sample looks like

```
@Repository("hrdb.UserDao")
public class UserDao extends WMGenericDaoImpl <User, Integer> {

   @Autowired
   @Qualifier("hrdbTemplate")
   private HibernateTemplate template;

   public HibernateTemplate getTemplate() {
        return this.template;
   }
}
```

And this is how our generic DAO impl looks like

```
public abstract class WMGenericDaoImpl<Entity extends Serializable, Identifier extends Serializable> implements WMGenericDao<Entity, Identifier> {

    private Class<Entity> entityClass;

    public abstract HibernateTemplate getTemplate();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        if (getTemplate() == null)
            throw new RuntimeException("hibernate template is not set.");

        ParameterizedType genericSuperclass = (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        this.entityClass = (Class<Entity>) genericSuperclass.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    public Entity create(Entity entity) {
        Identifier identifier = (Identifier) getTemplate().save(entity);
        return findById(identifier);
    }

    public void update(Entity entity) {
        getTemplate().update(entity);
        getTemplate().flush();
    }

    public void delete(Entity entity) {
        getTemplate().delete(entity);
    }

    public Entity findById(Identifier entityId) {
        return getTemplate().get(entityClass, entityId);
    }
}
```

Ofcourse here is WMGenericDao Interface,

```
public interface WMGenericDao<Entity, Identifier> {

    Entity create(Entity entity);

    void update(Entity entity);

    void delete(Entity entity);

    Entity findById(Identifier entityId);
}
```

And HibernateTemplate is declared in spring.xml.
With this kind of implementation we are able to generate All DAO class in the reverse engineering process by using hibernate template provided by spring.